# Display Int ArrayList in RecyclerView (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display an ArrayList of Integers inside of a RecyclerView, the Integer values in the ArrayList are downloaded from JSON, all that is done, the thing I need help with is to display them in a RecyclerView.

Here's part of the MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainViewModel viewmodel;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(JsonData.rideList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    viewmodel = new ActivityMainViewModel();
    binding.setViewmodel(viewmodel);
}
```

Here's the MainAdapter class:

```
    class MainAdapter extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

int ride;
private ArrayList<Integer> rideList;

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> rideList)
{
    this.rideList = rideList;
}

@Override
public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.rideHeight.setText(ride);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return (null != rideList ? rideList.size() : 0);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView rideHeight;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        rideHeight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rideHeight_textView);
    }
}
```

}

Btw the rideHeight_textView is a TextView inside of the RecyclerView, dont know if that's the proper way to do it but that's what everyone else seems to be doing.

I know that it probably looks a mess but that's because I have been searching both on google and youtube on how to use RecyclerView so I might have mixed from different tutorials and tried somethings myself. All the tutorials I read or watched were using an ArrayList of objects while I'm using Int's.

Thanks!

Edit: Apparently I'm getting this fatal exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.remi.uppgift/com.example.remi.uppgift.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
```

Comment: change inside **bindviewholder** holder.rideHeight.setText(String.valueOf(rideList.get(poistion)));

Answer (score 1):

just remove this from your code

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    viewmodel = new ActivityMainViewModel();
    binding.setViewmodel(viewmodel);
```

it is enough for binding the view in `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(JsonData.rideList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

also

```
rideList.get(position) this is an `Interer` Value not `String`
```

so when you `SetText()` on `TextView` Please Typecast Value

```
holder.rideHeight.setText(String.valueOf(rideList.get(position)));
```

Comment: Didn't work, there seems to be a problem with the layoutmanager thing, check out my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.rideHeight.setText(""+ rideList.get(position));
}
```

else this

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.rideHeight.setText(String.valueOf(rideList.get(position)));
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work, there seems to be a problem with the layoutmanager thing, check out my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content view is set before accessing any views inside the layout.
Move `ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);` to the line right after the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

By the way, it is not necessary to use the `findViewById()` to access the recycler view. In databinding, there is a convenient way to do it like

`ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding.recycler_view.setAdapter(...);`